# Power Bi Calculating number of days dynamically

Tags: powerbi

I am using a slicer to determine a certain periode of time (e.g. 01.10.19 - 31.10.19) and now I want Power Bi to calculate how many days are included (in this case it would be: 31). Of course the calculation needs to be updated every time I use the slicer. Is there any possibility to do so? I have literally no idea...

Comment: What does your data look like, and what is the goal you want to achieve with the number of days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a measure to calculate the difference between the max and min dates in your date table, which is filtered by this slicer. You can use [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datediff-function-dax) function for that. In this case the number of days will be calculated as:

```
Number of days = DATEDIFF(MIN('Calendar'[Date]); MAX('Calendar'[Date]); DAY) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do have a Calendar[Date] Table but when I use the slicer the table does not automatically get filtered. The first day always reamains in January 14 and the last day stays in September 19, so I get as result about 2100 days.

Comment: It looks like you put the slicer on the date field in your fact table. If put the calendar's date field in the slicer it will work (and imo it will be more efficient). Or you can use fact's date field in the measure, but you may miss some dates/days in case there are gaps in the data (e.g. 7 days in the slicer, from 1.1 to 7.1, but there are no rows for 1.1 in the data, so the measure will show 6 days).

Comment: Nevermind, I could just solve the Problem! Thank you very much :)
And thank you for the additional tips!